# What is the best practice when broadcasting heavy payloads?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast, payload

I have a `Service` which makes an API call every 10 seconds. And I need to pass the response data to the `Activity` or the `Fragment` and make relevant UI updates and other changes in the app.

I'm using `BroadcastReceiver`s to achieve this. My concern is about using it without compromising the system performance. I have two ways to achieve this.

**Method 1**

Send the heavy payload at once in a single Broadcast.

[image]

---

**Method 2**

Divide the payload into smaller parts and send multiple broadcasts each time.

[image]

---

> What would be the best practice and why?

Comment: Please do not use system broadcasts to send messages within your own app, and local broadcasts were deprecated last year. Have your repository make the API calls periodically and publish those results via a reactive framework (`LiveData`, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, etc.).

Comment: Inter-process communication (IPC) affects performance. From a performance standpoint, ideally,you would keep all of this code in one process, and then you would not need IPC.

Comment: @CommonsWare Even with using something like `RxBus` what is prefered? Method 1 or 2?

Comment: When it is all within your own process, it may not make a difference. If it does, then it would depend a lot on the nature of the messages (e.g., would you be able to skip some work more easily if the messages are broken up as in method 2?). Those details are specific to your app, and we cannot guess at them very well.